# SSIS-DB2 : Data changes value when inserted into table

Tags: ssis, db2

I have an issue when inserting data into a DB2 database table.
I follow a value of a column in the DataFlow, let's say the value I'm talking about is 0.0075, it's read properly from a csv file, and when I check the value right before insert in a DataViewer it's still the same value, but once it's on the table the value becomes 7.499.
Also for some lines the values don't change, let's say I have 0.023 it remanes the same.
Do you know what can lead to such behavior? Have you come across this issue?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the target table?  Give more details about how you access DB2, is it a linked-table in SQL-server? Give details about the column datatype in the target DB2 table, and the datatype in your application.

Comment: There's no triggers, nothing running in background.
It's really as simple as taking info from a csv file and put it in a work table. Types are different, in the csv file it's double-precision float(DT-R8) and in table it's numeric(6,3), but this shouldn't change value

Comment: Ask your DB2 DBA to show the value that DB2 receives from SSIS (to determine where the change happens). Ask the DBA to confirm the value in the DB2 column independently of your tooling (just in case there is some problem viewing the data). Float to decimal will involve some rounding , but your example was out by 3 decimal places.

Comment: I'll try to, we don't have a dedicated DBA, so not easy to reach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using double precision float, try using DT_NUMERIC where you can specify the scale and precision when reading from source.

Comment: Thanks it worked
I still don't understand the strange behavior though

Comment: That is expected behaviour when using float.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems